# Envi Heater and safe distance to hang art

Tags: heater

We just moved into a place that has an Envi wall heater. I am concerned that I can't hang art above the unit. A search on their FAQ does not indicate what is a safe distance to hang art above the unit.

Does anyone have any experience with this type of heater and hanging electronics or art above it?

https://www.eheat.com/envi-high-efficiency-whole-room-plug-in-electric-panel-heater-hh1012t/

Answer (score 2):

Get a stick-on thermometer, and stick it on the wall where you want to put stuff.  See what the temperature is.  That will tell you if it is a safe temperature range.